# SSRS 2008r2 cutting off report descriptions in main display page in report manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We upgraded from 2008 to 2008R2 and the report and folder descriptions only show about 1 line of data in report manager.  Mousing over the report will display the full description.  Is there a way to display the full description in report manager or to revert to the 2008 report manager appearance?

Comment: Just to get clairity, you mean you're looking at the Report Manager URL (generally http://myserver/Reports)?  And I assume you're in "details" view?

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging and it looks like the Report Manager webiste is really a full-featured ASP.Net website being run by the DLLs under c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server[your MSRS instance]\Reporting Services\ReportManager.

Unfortunately, the bulk of the web page generation is done by closed DLLs (\bin\ReportingServicesWebUserInterface.dll), but the style sheets are open & available for modification.  You can't change the class names, you can edit the actual styles in \Styles\ReportingServices.css.

For your items, the style class name is "msrs-itemDescription".  I had some success changing the style from this:

```
p.msrs-itemDescription  { white-space: nowrap; width: 250px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; font-size:10pt; color:Gray; }
```

To this:

```
p.msrs-itemDescription  { white-space: normal; width: 250px; overflow: auto; font-size:10pt; color:Gray; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing Hidden from

{ white-space: nowrap; width: 250px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; font-size:10pt; color:Gray; }

Will allow all text to display